# Displaying a pop up message in javascript for my rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Question is in my rails application I have a method in my user controller that does an auto populate. This fills in a form for a new user when they are signing up .when they fill in my emp_id text box it looks at my employee table  which is where I am pulling this data from if an ID matches an what the emp_id they typed it will auto populate thier emp_first_name and emp_last_name. I am able to have a pop up message when the data returns has data but, Im stuck on how to make it show a message if no data exist for that perticular emp_id...

This is my controller

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  def populate_form

    @visual = Visual.find_by_id(params[:emp_id])


    if @visual.nil?

      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :unprocessable_entity, flash[:error] => "Error No ID found." }   
        #This didn't work no message displays..
      end

    else


      @emp_first_name = @visual.first_name

      @emp_last_name = @visual.last_name

        render :json => {

           :emp_first_name => @emp_first_name,
           :emp_last_name => @emp_last_name

        }
     end
   end
```

This is my view..

```
<div class='row form-group'>
  <div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 text-right'>
    <%= f.text_field :emp_id, tabindex: 1, id: 'emp_id', autofocus: true, placeholder: t( 'login_label' ), class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='row form-group'>
  <div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 text-right'>
    <%= f.text_field :emp_first_name, tabindex: 1, id: 'emp_first_name', autofocus: true, placeholder: t( 'emp_first' ), class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='row form-group'>
  <div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 text-right'>
    <%= f.text_field :emp_last_name, tabindex: 1, id: 'emp_last_name', autofocus: true, placeholder: t( 'emp_last' ), class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
```

Here is my app.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#emp_id').change(function() {
     var url = "/user/populate_form?emp_id="+$(this).val();
     $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
       if(!(data.emp_first_name === undefined))
         $('#emp_first_name').val(data.emp_first_name);
       if(!(data.emp_last_name === undefined))
         $('#emp_last_name').val(data.emp_last_name);
       if('#emp_first_name' === null) {
         alert('Fail employee ID wasn't found please try again with a valid employee ID.');
       } else  {
         alert('Your employee ID has been found please fill in the email and password fields then click submit to register.');
       }
     });}
   );
 });
```

Comment: What exactly did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.You can use different [ajax callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to check if json response is a failure and then show the error message.you can use a blank placeholder for showing alert messages..such as:-

**use this in the controller to show json error**

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  def populate_form

    @visual = Visual.find_by_id(params[:emp_id])


    if @visual.present?
        respond_to do |format|
            @emp_first_name = @visual.first_name
            @emp_last_name = @visual.last_name
             render :json => {

                 :emp_first_name => @emp_first_name,
                 :emp_last_name => @emp_last_name
                              }
    else       
            format.js { render :json => "id not present", :status => 400 }
            format.html { render :json => "id not present" , :status => 400 }

         end    
     end
   end
```

**view file**,with placeholder

```
<div id="show_alert" style="display:none;"></div>
```

**js code**,to show alert

```
 $('#emp_id').change(function() {
       var url = "/user/populate_form?emp_id="+$(this).val();
       $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
         if(!(data.emp_first_name === undefined))
         $('#emp_first_name').val(data.emp_first_name);
         if(!(data.emp_last_name === undefined))
         $('#emp_last_name').val(data.emp_last_name);
          }).done(function (response) {
                  if (response.success == 'success') {               
                      //alert('success');    
                        $("#show_alert").html("<span class='text-success marginl10' ><b>Your employee ID has been found please fill in the email and password fields then click submit to register..</b></span>")
                  } else {
                      //alert('fail');
                      $("#show_alert").html("<span class='text-danger     marginl10' ><b>Fail employee ID wasn't found please try again with a valid employee ID.</b></span>").show();
                  }
       });
     }
   );
 });
```

Comment: @Legendary...its not typo..he need to catch the response if error comes...so i have edited my answer.have a look ..

Comment: Ok for now, just i dont understand, why u want change code, when u see syntax error? @Milind

Comment: @Legendary.. you cannot use flash in json response..it needs to send a json response instead of flash..that we need to use it in js code...

Comment: @Milind you answer works for if it finds a valid id but still no luck if the id doesnt exist. My js is watching the emp_first_name text box but, it seems to not work when no data is returned for the emp_first_name, but when an emp_id matches and fills in the emp_first_name I get the your employee id has been found-----....My question is how can I get it to tell me that no id was found

Comment: @Legendary..see in the controller...he is not sending a proper json response ...so how can the js catch the error ...he needs to use ajax callback to catch both success and error..which i have used...

Comment: @Milind I tried your updated answer and got this NoMethodError (undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/user_controller.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in populate_form'
  app/controllers/user_controller.rb:24:in `populate_form

Comment: @Snowman88..i have changed controller code..pls check and verify

Comment: @Snowman88.. i will appreciate if you pls accept  my answer by checking the left check sigh

Comment: @Milind - <offtop> "my life for rating"  </offtop>

Answer (score 0):

controller:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  def populate_form

    @visual = Visual.find_by_id(params[:emp_id])


    unless @visual.present?

      render json: {user: @user, status: :unprocessable_entity, error: 404}

    else


      @emp_first_name = @visual.first_name

      @emp_last_name = @visual.last_name

        render :json => {

           :emp_first_name => @emp_first_name,
           :emp_last_name => @emp_last_name

        }
  end
end
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#emp_id').change(function() {
     var url = "/user/populate_form?emp_id="+$(this).val();
     $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
       if( !( data.emp_first_name === undefined ))       $('#emp_first_name').val(data.emp_first_name);
       if( !( data.emp_last_name.length === undefined )) $('#emp_last_name').val(data.emp_last_name);
       if( (data.error * 1) == 404) {
         alert("Fail employee ID wasn't found please try again with a valid employee ID.");
       } else  {
         alert("Your employee ID has been found please fill in the email and password fields then click submit to register.");
       }
     });
   }
   );
 });
```

Comment: When I added the parenthese after emp_first_name it gave me this error   SyntaxError: expected expression, got '===' @Legendary

Comment: Can u show ur console.log(data); right after ajax.success

Comment: $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
       console.log(data);   and show to us from js console